# Add custom fields from CSV to ListView, and populate values using left join on ListViewItem name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, file

I've created a kind of file explorer with windows forms, with a `TreeView` for showing folders, and a `ListView` to show the contents of each folder, like below:

[image]

What I want to do is add a bunch of extra columns based on the contents of a CSV file using some kind of left join based on file name. A snippet of the file:

```
Name,Classification
transcript.txt,Primary
```

So in my case, my form above would have a 4th column called `Classification`. And for the file `transcript.txt`, the value for that column would be `Primary`. The file `newfile.txt` would just have no value.

The real CSV file would have multiple columns.

I'm just not really sure where to start here. In the code below, I'll probably need some kind of loop where it says `// CODE HERE` which will add the new column names from the CSV, then somehow populate them. I did find a way to load the CSV file into memory (with each column being in its own list) but don't know how to utilise it.

Snippet of my code below:

```
void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
            ListViewItem item = null;

            ...

            foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);

                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                    { 
                        new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"),
                        new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())

                        // CODE HERE
       
                    };

                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

EDIT:

This is how I'm loading the CSV into memory (just a copy/paste from someone else's code).

```
   private void LoadCSV()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.csv"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                listA.Add(values[0]);
                listB.Add(values[1]);
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since the file name in the CSV appears to have no path, it's assumed these names are unique. In that case, add the names and the associated *value* to a `Dictionary<string, string>`, so you can get the *value* (`Primary`) associated to a Key (`transcript.txt`) just using the Dictionary Key (the file name).

Comment: Thanks @Jimi I've started to do it in a really hacky way. But dictionary makes sense. Just need to work out how to use a dict in C#. Would I need a different dictionary for every column name in the CSV? There could be a dozen or so. I only showed two as an example.

Comment: You need just one Dictionary. It doesn't matter (to an extent) how many CSV files you have. What matters is if these names are unique, or if the path is included in the file name. If the file names are unique, in a way or another, then preload the Dictionary (or reload it when the folder changes) and just use the file name as the Key to get the associated value. See the `.TryGetValue()` method.

Comment: To clarify, there would only be one CSV. However, there could be multiple columns in that CSV. e.g. `Name`, `Classification`, `Doc type`, `Author`, etc. So if it's just one dictionary, would the key by `File` and the the value a list of column names?

Comment: Well, this is not what you wrote in the question. Specify the actual content of this CSV file. You have to be precise -- In your case, you'd need a `Dictionary<string, class>`, where `class` is a class object that contains the details related to a file name. Usually, CSV files are deserialized to class objects. Or DataTables. -- You prefer a class object here.